# How to create a JSON Array from a two-dimensional array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash

I have a two-dimensional array like this:

```
[
  ["01fe237f804a5eff182dcded115c37d3", 0.0140845], 
  ["026e5f1f7f026bf3c763523206aa44bf", 0.03448275], 
  ["04a1c3c79773bd1ecc0372a991adc815", 0.04617604]
]
```

I'd like to create a hash first, then convert it to JSON, so that the result looks like the following:

```
[{address: "01fe237f804a5eff182dcded115c37d3", value: 0.0140845},
{address: "026e5f1f7f026bf3c763523206aa44bf", value: 0.03448275},
{address: "04a1c3c79773bd1ecc0372a991adc815", value: 0.04617604}]
```

Comment: 1. If you know that `require ‘json’; arr.to_json` converts an array `arr` to a JSON string you should have limited your question to the part you don’t understand: how to convert an array of two-element arrays to an array of hashes with specified keys. 2. Always simplify your examples. Here `arr = [["01fe", 0.014],  ["026e", 0.034],  ["04a1", 0.046]]` would have sufficed. 3. As I did in #2, assign a variable (e.g., ’arr`) to each of the example’s inputs so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them...

Comment: ...4. Always show the desired result of an example as a *valid* Ruby object. You show what appears to be a string but strings are surrounded by double or single quotes. (If  you add double quotes you need to escape the inner double quotes.) This may seem a quibble but some readers are fussy about that. 5. This is a pure-Ruby question so you should not have a Rails’ tag. 6. Your question is implicit (“How do I do that?”). Often that will provoke the comment, “What is your question?”. It’s best to always state your question...

Comment: ...7. The tags “array” and “hash” are probably unnecessary as it’s unlikely that such common objects would be used as search terms.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see the "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[ask]". We want to see your effort toward solving this. Did you research it? If so, where and why didn't it help? Did you write code? If so, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, and what was that problem? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the code for you which is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired result is still a Ruby hash. To transform it call `map` on the array and create a hash for each entry:

```
a = [
  ["01fe237f804a5eff182dcded115c37d3", 0.0140845],
  ["026e5f1f7f026bf3c763523206aa44bf", 0.03448275],
  ["04a1c3c79773bd1ecc0372a991adc815", 0.04617604]
]

a.map{ |e| {address: e[0], value: e[1]} }
```

This returns the desired result.

If you want to create a JSON string, require `json` and do the following:

```
require 'json'

a = [
  ["01fe237f804a5eff182dcded115c37d3", 0.0140845],
  ["026e5f1f7f026bf3c763523206aa44bf", 0.03448275],
  ["04a1c3c79773bd1ecc0372a991adc815", 0.04617604]
]

a.map{|e| {address: e[0], value: e[1]} }.to_json
```

This will encode the result to the following string:

```
"[{\"address\":\"01fe237f804a5eff182dcded115c37d3\",\"value\":0.0140845},{\"address\":\"026e5f1f7f026bf3c763523206aa44bf\",\"value\":0.03448275},{\"address\":\"04a1c3c79773bd1ecc0372a991adc815\",\"value\":0.04617604}]"
```

Comment: simple & neat +1, I have done with different approach

Comment: Some may prefer `a.map { |v1,v2| { address: v1, value: v2 }  }.to_json` for readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below,

```
require 'json'
keys = [:address, :value]
arr.map { |values| Hash[keys.zip(values)] }.to_json
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `Hash[keys.zip(values)]` can be replaced with `keys.zip(values).to_h`, though I don't think either is preferred. Your answer has the advantage that if embeded in a method with arguments `arr` and `keys`, `keys` can be any size (as opposed to only working when there are two keys).